# Dired as an FTP client

Tags: dired, ftp

I don't know whether this is possible or not.
I know I can edit remote files, but what I am looking for is a setup like this:

- one buffer with dired on my local directory
- one buffer with dired on the remote directory

Sort of a visual aid when updating my files on the remote directory. Marking multiple files and updating them via FTP would be quick if it was possible from this kind of configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You don't need to (explicitly) use FTP.  Just use `C` in Dired to copy from one directory to the other. You can copy in either direction: from local to remote or remote to local.

For example:

- Dired buffer #1 is for local directory `~jpepin/mydir/`.
- Dired buffer #1 is for remote directory `/foo.bar.toto.com:/home/jpepin/mydir/`.

---

(***Tip:*** Create a Dired *bookmark* to your remote directory (and perhaps another to your local directory). Dired bookmarks are especially handy if you use [**Bookmark+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). You can also bookmark a Dired tree: a set of Dired bookmarks.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at [Sunrise Commander](https://github.com/escherdragon/sunrise-commander) ([EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander))?

It builds on Dired to provide a 2 pane file manager similar to Norton Commander and Midnight Commander.

This can let you view both directories (as long as you can access the second directory through TRAMP it should be able to be accessed through Dired).

Commands at that point mirror Dired where applicable.